# how to skip a info when the box already as this info?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a code that perfectly works to get some info from a sheet and copy it to an other when a word is encoutered on the two sheets.
But my sheet is so big that it takes about 3 minutes to get and wrote all the info from one sheet to the other.

```
function INFO() {

  var PROsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("1");
  var REA_PROJsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("2");


  //list 01
  var projnamePRO = PROsheet.getRange(5, 2, PROsheet.getLastRow()).getValues(); //list 01
  var projnameREA = REA_PROJsheet.getRange(2, 2, REA_PROJsheet.getLastRow()).getValues(); //list 02

  var list01Columns = [1, 4, 5];
  var list02Columns = [1, 2, 3];
  
  for (i = 0; i < projnameREA.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < projnamePRO.length; j++) {
      if (projnameREA[i][0] == projnamePRO[j][0] && projnameREA[i][0] !== "") {
        if (projnameREA[i] === projnamePRO[j]) return;//new line added
        for (k = 0; k < list01Columns.length; k++) {
         
          REA_PROJsheet.getRange(i + 2, list02Columns[k]).setValue(PROsheet.getRange(j + 5, list01Columns[k]).getValue()
          )
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

so I have try to had a line to skip the writing of the info, if the info in the box is already wrote :

```
        if (projnameREA[i] === projnamePRO[j]) return;
```

but apparently it don't work because if I run the code a second time, it take 3 minutes again.

Basically, I would the code be able to :

- wrote the info if the box is empty
- wrote the info again if it have change
- skip and be faster, if the info on the boxe is already the same that it is about to copy

what am I doing wrong ?

What can I do ?

Comment: Have you considered  `indexOf` to search for the "search name" in a 1D Column of names. This saves having to loop. `indexOf` [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) returns "the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present." The index is zero-based, BTW. You can use the index value to identify the row number of the matching name, and write a single `getRange`/`setValue` or maybe even `copyTo`.

Comment: If you don't mind the question (and sorry if it is silly). Are you looking to compare that both arrays are exactly the same or just looking if a particular value exists in the comparing array?

Comment: One solution is to avoid writing `setValue` multiple times within the loop. Have you considered writing to a temporary array and then updating the target with the array values as the last line of code?

Comment: `if (projnameREA[i] === projnamePRO[j]) return;//new line added` Would you please explain the purpose of this line. To the best of my knowledge, it will **always** evaluate as false, so any intent is likely to fail.

Comment: The words on ProSheet are in Column B (`PROsheet.getRange(5, 2, PROsheet.getLastRow()).getValues()`); the words on Rea Sheet are also in Column B (`REA_PROJsheet.getRange(2, 2, REA_PROJsheet.getLastRow()).getValues()`). However when you copy values from Pro to Rea, it appears that you copy Pro-Column D (`list01Columns = [1, 4, 5]`) over Rea-Column B (`list02Columns = [1, 2, 3]`). The effect is to overwrite the word that you have just matched. Is this your intention?

Comment: @ tedinoz "The effect is to overwrite the word that you have just matched. Is this your intention?", no, it wasn't my purpose, it's a small mistake when I have tried to simplify my code to ask a question... it should copy the value from column B into column B, in order to change the cell from a drop-down menu to a text writen value.

Comment: @Tedinoz, "

One solution is to avoid writing setValue multiple times within the loop. Have you considered writing to a temporary array and then updating the target with the array values as the last line of code?"
Could you please gave me further information about this method ?

Comment: `I have a code that perfectly works to get some info from a sheet and copy it to an other when a word is encoutered on the two sheets.` I know that the "word" is in Column B but that's all. Would you please provide more information; e.g. is the spreadsheet being used by other users while this script is running?, is this a one-off or regular task, how many rows of data, how many matches on Column B do you expect, are both columns sorted on Column B, etc.

Comment: It's a regular task 5 to 10 times a day and the sheet is used by many other people, that is the reason why I need the code to be fast ! there is about 40 matches on the columns for about 350 row in the spreadsheet, I hope it helps !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a spreadsheet with two sheets ("PRO" and "REA"). In column B of each sheet are words. You want to find search the words on "REA" for matches on "PRO". Where a match exists, you want to copy cells from certain columns in the row on "PRO" to certain columns in the matching row on "REA".

Your problem is that you have a large spreadsheet and you are currently unable to to complete the matching exercise within the 6 minutes execution limit.

The reason that the script is taking so long is that for every match, there is a `getValue` and `setValue` to update **EACH** value from "PRO" to "REA". In your draft, you are updating 3 cells. That's 6 calls to the spreadsheet.

In the answer, the update from "PRO" to REA" is simplified. There are zero `getValue` and a `setValue` for each column to copy. The effect on script execution is significant. Had the columns on the target sheet been contiguous (or at least closer together), the values might have been updated in a single `setValues` per match.

**OPTIMISATION**

- **Before**

---

```
for (k = 0; k < list01Columns.length; k++) {
  REA_PROJsheet.getRange(i + 2, list02Columns[k]).setValue(
    PROsheet.getRange(j + 5, list01Columns[k]).getValue()
  )
}
```

---

- a `getValue` and `setValue` to update **EACH** value from "PRO" to "REA".
- updating 3 cells = 6 calls to the spreadsheet

---

- **After**

---

```
for (k = 0; k < list01Columns.length; k++) {
  reaSheet.getRange(i + 2,list02Columns[k]).setValue(valuesPro[j][(list01Columns[k]-1)])
}
```

---

- `getValues` on "PRO" covers columns A-E and first row to last row.

  - no additional `getValue` is required when updating from "PRO" to "REA"
- in the "k" loop, there is a single `setValue` per Column.

---

```
function updateREAProloop() {

  var proSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("1")
  var reaSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("2")

  // list 1 PRO 
  var proStartRow = 5
  var proColumnCount = 5 // column E
  var lrPro = proSheet.getLastRow()
  var rangePro = proSheet.getRange(proStartRow,1,lrPro-proStartRow+1,proColumnCount)
  var valuesPro = rangePro.getValues()

  // list 2 REA
  var reaStartRow = 2
  var reaColumnCount = 2 // column B
  var lrRea = reaSheet.getLastRow()
  var rangeRea = reaSheet.getRange(reaStartRow,1,lrRea-reaStartRow+1,reaColumnCount)
  var valuesRea = rangeRea.getValues()

  var list01Columns = [1, 4, 5] // PRO
  var list02Columns = [6, 8, 20] // REA
  
  for (i = 0; i < valuesRea.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < valuesPro.length; j++) {
      if (valuesRea[i][1] == valuesPro[j][1]) {
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: i="+i+", j="+j+", REA name = "+valuesRea[i][1]+", Pro Name = "+ valuesPro[j][1])
        for (k = 0; k < list01Columns.length; k++) {
          // Logger.log("DEBUG: k="+k+", value = "+valuesPro[j][list01Columns[k]])
          // Logger.log("DEBUG: Pro Name = "+ valuesPro[j][1]+", PRO Col#: "+[list01Columns[k]]+"("+(+[list01Columns[k]]-1)+") REA Col#: "+list02Columns[k]+"("+(+[list02Columns[k]]-1)+") , PRO Value to copy: "+valuesPro[j][(list01Columns[k]-1)]+", REA target range = "+reaSheet.getRange(i + 2,list02Columns[k]).getA1Notation())
          reaSheet.getRange(i + 2,list02Columns[k]).setValue(valuesPro[j][(list01Columns[k]-1)])
        }
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi,thank you very much, I have done many test and try some modification with the code you did. But I don't understand what can I do to write the info from the `var list01Columns = [1, 4, 5];` in the Prosheet with a different order and in different columns such as on my example. like `var list02Columns = [6, 8, 20];` I have try to add a line `var list02Columns = [6, 8, 20]` and then to replace the set value line by `REA_PROJsheet.getRange(i + 2, list02Columns[k]).setValues(setValuesArray)` but it don't look that easy

Comment: @antho2B OK. I've updated the script - note: that the **entire** script has changed. There is a `setValue` for each column value to be updated. In my test data, the script runs in about 5 seconds (total). Had `list02Columns` been adjacent (or at least closer together-it's a big gap between #8 and #20), I might have persisted with the temporary array approach. Anyway, I shall be interested to hear what execution time you get on your spreadsheet.

Comment: Hi @Tedinoz, thank you so much, it's perfectly working, the only line I changed is : `if (valuesRea[i][1] == valuesPro[j][1] && valuesRea[i][0] !== "")`, to skip the blank line. It change from 3minutes to 16seconds... quite fast ! thank you so much !

Comment: I didn't think that there were so many blank rows. Another approach would be to test for a blank in `valuesRea[i][1]` immediately after `for (i = 0; i < valuesRea.length; i++) {` This would stop the "j" loop altogether. Anyway, glad that the execution speed has decreased. BTW, one thing that I didn't address was the potential effect of other users accessing/editing the spreadsheet while the function is running. Watch out for that.