# how to skip the creation of a sheet if the sheet already exist

Tags: google-apps-script

from different sources I have been able to create a code that take an existing sheet (the "TEMPLATE" one) and then copy and rename it.

But I have a problem :

If in the sheet list that I wan't to create, one of them already exist, the code won't skip it and create the other one.
Let say that I want to create all thoose sheets :
  `var copy_sheets = ['info','souces','subtotal','list','list01'];`

If in a spreadsheet, the sheet `'subtotal'` already exist, the code will create the 2 first sheet `'info','souces'` and then stop.
How can I skip the `'subtotal'` sheet, and create the `'list','list01'` sheets ?

here is my code :

```
function copysheet01() {

  var TEMPLATEsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("TEMPLATE");


  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var copy_sheets = ['info','souces','subtotal','list','list01'];
    copy_sheets.forEach(sheet=>{            
    var dupl_sheet=TEMPLATEsheet.copyTo(ss);
    dupl_sheet.setName(sheet);                   
    });

}
```

I have try to manage something with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76423832/how-to-skip-a-info-when-the-box-already-as-this-info), but cannot figure it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### SUGGESTION

Based on what I've understood, you would like to be able to create a new sheet that would be based on the list you provided. You may use the following code which would check if the sheet already exists in the spreadsheet that you have and add any new ones you might put in later on.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Template");
  var copySheets = ['info','souces','subtotal','list','list01'];
  var existingSheets = ss.getSheets();

  var checkSheetNames = existingSheets.map(function (sheet) {
    return sheet.getName();
  });

  copySheets.forEach(function (sheet) {
    if (checkSheetNames.indexOf(sheet) == -1) {
      var duplicateSheets = templateSheet.copyTo(ss);
      duplicateSheets.setName(sheet);
    }
  });
}
```

### OUTPUT

[image: OUTPUT]

### REFERENCES

- [Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets)
- [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Answer (score 1):

You have to check whether the new sheet name is already present. [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)  should come in handy.

```
function copysheet01() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const TEMPLATEsheet = ss.getSheetByName('TEMPLATE');
  const alreadyPresentSheetsNames = new Set(
    ss.getSheets().map((sh) => sh.getName())
  );
  const toCopyShNames = new Set([
    'info',
    'souces',
    'subtotal',
    'list',
    'list01',
  ]);
  toCopyShNames.forEach((toCopyShName) => {
    if (!alreadyPresentSheetsNames.has(toCopyShName)) {
      ss.insertSheet(toCopyShName, { options: { template: TEMPLATEsheet } });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: thx ! One more question, How would you do it if the list you want to create `const toCopyShNames` was a result of a precedent `var PROJECT_LIST_CLEAN` which the content look like that in the logger : `[[ALPINES MUSEUM DAV], [ARROMANCHES], [BELVEDERE MUSEUM], [BERGBAUMUSEUM OELSNITZ], [BLOIS_MAQUETTE], [BOTANIKA BREMEN],.... ]`, because if I juste replace the content like that `new Set([PROJECT_LIST_CLEAN]);` it don't works...

Comment: @emilianoSala It's a 2D array. So, flatten it before passing to set(`new Set(PROJECT_LIST_CLEAN.flat())`)